# Question on grep

Tags: linux, shell

Out of many results returned by grepping a particular pattern, if I want to use all the results one after the other in my script, how can I go about it?For e.g. I grep for .der in a certificate folder which returns many results. I want to use each and every .der certificate listed from the grep command. How can I use one file after the other out of the grep result?

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually grepping content, or just filenames?  If it's file names, you'd be better off using the `find` command:

```
find /path/to/folder -name "*.der" -exec some other commands {} ";"
```

It should be quicker in general.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `grep -l`. This ensures you only get every file once. `-l` is used to print the name of each file only, not the matches.

Then, you can loop on the results:

```
for file in `grep ....`
do
    # work on $file
done
```

Also note that if you have spaces in your filenames, there is a ton of possible issues. See [Looping through files with spaces in the names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names) on the Unix&Linux stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output as part of a `for` loop, something like:

```
for cert in $(grep '\.der' *) ; do
    echo ${cert} # or something else
done
```

Of course, if those `der` things are actually files (and you're using `ls | grep` to get them), you can directly use the files:

```
for cert in *.der ; do
    echo ${cert} # or something else
done
```

In both cases, you may need to watch out for arguments with embedded spaces.